# Retrieving An Icon File From A GitHub Repository In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, tkinter, ico

I want to know how I could retrieve an `ICO` (icon) file from a GitHub repository. And then after that, put it as the `iconbitmap` for a `Tkinter` window.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Feedback And Rating")
window.geometry("300x350")
window.iconbitmap("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngusAU293/Application-Assets/main/Feedback%20And%20Rating%20Example/icon.ico")
```

I'm using Python `3`.

Comment: Do you have a URL for the file you want to get? Do you know how to download files from the Internet using Python? If you put those two things together, does it solve the problem? Otherwise, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: But aside from that, why does the program need to retrieve the icon every time? Why not just... download it yourself, and put it in an appropriate folder locally, and have the program load that?

Comment: The reason is, is that I have this Tkinter program, and once I'm able to set the window icon as an image from a GitHub repository, I will convert it into an executable. Then I would be able to share it without having to also share the icon file.

Comment: It is still better to download the ICON file and embed it into the executable instead.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Refer [this](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html) for details if you use `PyInstaller`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file using `urllib.request`, then set the icon to the downloaded file. Or, as Karl suggested, download the icon beforehand and place in the SAME directory as the Python file, so that the application doesn't need internet to run.

```py
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Feedback And Rating")
window.geometry("300x350")
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngusAU293/Application-Assets/main/Feedback%20And%20Rating%20Example/icon.ico", "icon.ico")
window.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
```